# Replacement Power supply for Xmas lights!

Tags: power-supply, power, dc, amperage, watts

[image]I have hit these boards as a last resort hoping someone may know a solution....

I have some xmas lights, they are a roll of 50 and each light rated at 0.06w or 0.02A.

I have added 33 lights to it and now have a total of 83 lights.

The existing power supply is 31v 3.6w so its not going to cut it.

The lights run in a series so you can change the flashing etc.

I didnt add the 33 on the end, instead I bought 2 sets of 50 and cut off the excess from the end of one set leaving 33.

Then I linked the start of both wires together and then to the PSU. What happened is the first 50 were very dull and the last 33 very bright.

I want to run all these from one Power supply.

I can't seem to find a 31v 5W power supply online.

My question is, if the lights need 0.06w/0.02A each, can I use another combination e.g. with a 12v transformer?

[image]

Thanks

Andy

Comment: For what [max] voltage is each light rated?

Comment: it says on the box: Rating: 3v 0.02a 0.06w

Comment: Are the lights all wired in series? In parallel? In several series chains, each paralleled?

Comment: Are these LEDs as Arsenal guessed? You'd better post a picture or link to the manufacturer description. The same goes for your "existing power supply".

Answer (score 1):

Something doesn't add up here, 50*0.06 W = 3 W, 50*0.02 A = 1A * 31 V = 31 W. So there must be some serial / parallel wiring going on.

**First guess:**

Probably 10 lights in series and that 5 times parallel. That would result in a total current from the 31 V supply of 0.1 A. That would be 3.1 W which is close enough to the 3 W.

It sounds like it could be a white/blue LED (~3.1 V forward voltage) with 20 mA forward current.

So if you just cut 33 from a different strip, the last three will probably not light up as you cut the connection.

For your power supply, if the connection is like I imagine, they won't light up when you apply 12 V to them.

I found a replacement supply for some HP printer with 31 V and 1.4 A output capability, I guess you could use that to power your lights. ([HP 0950-4340 31V 1450mA](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00565VGAW))

---

**Second guess:**

If they are bulbs (totally forgotten that those are still around in 2015), I can think of another configuration how they are connected:

Basically it's a series connection of 5 parallel bulbs 10 times. (10s5p)

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f2a7Bs.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

I have drawn only part of the schematic. It's basically a large resistor net. The sum current will be 0.1 A and at every 5 parallel connection point the current splits up fairly evenly across the 5 bulbs so each of them gets 20 mA.

The resistance of a complete chain is:

10 times (5 times 150 Ohms in parallel) in series = 300 Ohms.

As you cut off and rewired your second chain you have changed the configuration to:

6 times (5 times 150 Ohms in parallel) in series to (3 times 150 Ohms in parallel) = 230 Ohms.

Then you put those 2 chains in parallel (which is okay).

**But** bad things are happening in your modified chain: the current flowing though that part is increased. There is a total current of 134 mA flowing, so 34% more than what is supposed to flow. The bulbs will burn out rather quickly.

Even worse for the last 3, as they have to share the 134 mA as well, so 45 mA, more than 2 times of what they are supposed to handle.

In the current configuration, your modified chain will die as soon as you put them onto a power supply which is able to handle the current (which would be 0.25 A, so roughly 7.75 W).

To get the result you want:

- single supply for both chains

You have to add a 75 Ohm resistor in parallel of the last 3 bulbs and 90 Ohms in series to the whole chain. Both resistor must be able to handle the power. The 75 Ohm resistor would need a rating of at least 250 mW and the 90 Ohms one needs a rating of 1 W, preferably higher, so that it stays cooler.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f2GuYL.png)</sup>

---

Comment: I'm guessing he mixed up his  "existing power supply" spec so it's actually 31W 3.6V or something like that.

Comment: @RespawnedFluff That seems unlikely. You can't simply parallel individual LEDs without huge variations in brightness, and running 10A over thin wires is a bad idea.

Comment: Hi, I put this in my OP "The existing power supply is 31v 3.6w so its not going to cut it."

Comment: you are indeed correct and it is a series so you can change the flashing etc.

I didnt add the 33 on the end, instead I linked the start of both wires together.

what happened is the first 50 were very dull and the last 33 very bright.

Comment: Would any of these do the job:
http://www.ebay.co.uk/itm/Mains-Adapter-Power-Supply-30v-DC-500mA-Output-/181909533774?hash=item2a5aa7344e:g:vkkAAOSw37tWAGTO
 / http://www.ebay.co.uk/itm/30V-333mA-Printer-Power-Adapter-For-HP-Deskjet-1000-1050-2050-2060-3050-3052-/271682078470?hash=item3f41838706:g:h9sAAOSwuMFUcvLt / http://www.ebay.co.uk/itm/HP-DESKJET-1000-PRINTER-J110A-30v-333ma-Power-supply-adapter-with-lead-/201038633532?hash=item2eced61a3c:g:IMYAAOSwHnFVhkIl

Comment: @AndyBiggs You should edit your question with all the relevant information: How the lights were originally wired, how you added the new lights, what you observed when you did, and whether or not they're LEDs.

Comment: @AndyBiggs my "answer" was more a comment but too long for a comment. I was already staring at my glass ball and told you what I saw (my imagination) with the doubts I have. It is nearly impossible to get a specific answer if we have no idea which product you are talking about. "change the flashing etc." sounds a bit more involved than a simple string of lights.

Comment: Well there are 2 wires coming from the transformer but then after the 1st bulb there are 3 wires for a few bulbs then it switches to 2 wires for one bulb then back again. When I cut the bulbs off the end I had to connect 2 of the wires to make them come on.

Comment: Arsenal can you please post a link to the 31V transformer you found? I can only find 30V. Thanks

Comment: @AndyBiggs based on the additional information, I added a second guess and strongly advice against simply buying a more powerful power supply. There is a high risk, that your second (modified) chain will be destroyed if you use it without further modification. I've added a link to the thing I found as well.

Comment: Made a mistake in my calculations, fixed that, it's not quite as dramatic as in my first scenario, but still pretty bad.

Comment: Hi, I have just taken one apart and they are LED's. Can I still use the 31v 1.4A PSU?

Comment: I tried very hard to get the 33 bulbs onto the end of the other chain but after about 8 hours of trying everything I gave up.

Comment: are you saying that if I manager to get the additional 33 onto the end of the first set, it would work?

Comment: @AndyBiggs I cannot tell what works and what not as I am only guessing on how exactly the electrical connections and design is made. How many LEDs are actually connected with 3 wires before the next one with 2 wires? Can you post a picture of the power supply label? Do you see any current limiting device near the LED (like a small black, blue or brown thing)? I won't guess a third a time - maybe I should just delete the answer.

Comment: hi see pic i added. From the power supply 2 wires then after 1st bulb it goes to 3 wires until 5th bulb. After 5th bulb there are 2 wires and then5 more with 3. At the end it seems to loop[ back around.

Comment: 1. There are no limiting devices near the leds. 2. I have uploaded pics ot transformer and the wiring diagram.